# How to redirect a URI with a parenthesis in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a redirect in Rails 4

```
get '/something)', to: redirect("/something", status: 301), format: false
```

This doesn't work because parentheses are used for [optional parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters)

The error is:
`Racc::ParseError
parse error on value ")" (RPAREN)`

I tried both URL encoding `)` and escaping it `\)` and `\\)` but none of that worked. 
From my searches it seems that nobody ran into it before. It's rather strange indeed, but someone added the parentheses by mistake when linking to my site and now I want to redirect visitors to the correct one instead of the 404.

Comment: Why would one GET `/something)` ?

Comment: have you tried double quotation marks? `""`

Comment: Do you have nginx as the HTTP server?

Comment: Maybe just remove `)` from path?

Comment: I have a mistaken inbound link for `/something)` I don't want to show a 404 for this, but redirect to the right content while it's corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
constraints(path: /something\)/)  do 
  get '/:path', to: redirect("/something", status: 301), format: false
end
```

But ideal way is to put this redirection in you web server (eg: nginx)